# Take counts on pair categories using pandas to return a pivoted DatafFame from a tidy format DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like attached screenshot:
To create the DataFrame use the following snippet:

```
import pandas as pd 

buyer_id=['aaa',
'bbb',
'aac',
'aaa',
'bbb']

category=['mobile',
'laptop',
'laptop',
'grocery',
'mobile']

data_tuples = list(zip(buyer_id,category))

df=pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=['Buyer_ID','Category'])
```

I would like to create a new DataFrame that looks like the desired output in the screenshot. [image: Desired Output]
Basically take count of buyer_id on pairs- like Mobile & Mobile should return 2, Mobile & Grocery should return 1, Grocery & Laptop should return 0 etc.

Tried using groupby,pivot etc but doesn't work. Returns values for only same category i.e Mobile & Mobile.

One way may be to take pd.get_dummies() and summing two columns at a go on buyer_id level, and taking a count of rows for which sum equals to two, any easier way of doing this in Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), last change order of index and columns names by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and remove index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
i = df['Category'].unique()
df1 = df.merge(df, on='Buyer_ID')  
df = (pd.crosstab(df1['Category_x'],df1['Category_y'])
        .reindex(index=i, columns=i)
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df)
         mobile  laptop  grocery
mobile        2       1        1
laptop        1       2        0
grocery       1       0        1
```